# SEDE FAQ - small discrepancy - update day

Tags: bug, data-explorer, help

According to this https://data.stackexchange.com/help, SEDE is updated every Monday morning around 3:00 UTC. However, it is showing that it was last updated around Sunday morning around 3:00 UTC. And I confirmed this by running a query and it's showing updated results already. So shouldn't this be changed to Sunday instead of Monday?

[image: SEDE updated every monday morning]

Comment: Some recent times in last ~2 years that SEDE did not successfully update at this early Sunday morning UTC time. Sunday [Jan 11th 2015](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/246919/sede-data-migration-export-possible-failure), [June 14th 2015](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/258673/possible-sede-migration-failure), and [August 23rd 2015](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/264114/sede-migration-failed).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, if *automatic* updates continue to happen at that time. However, the most recent update was kicked off manually to apply a fix that was preventing some new data from appearing, so I'm not sure if that's the case yet.

I'll confirm either way and add "automatically" to the first sentence for clarification.

Comment: I'd say "typically" or "usually" rather than "automatically" to future-proof against the time when we inevitably don't update for whatever reason and someone inevitably reports it. :)

Comment: Usually when the update doesn't happen automatically like it's supposed to it's because something's wrong though, so isn't that kind of something you'd want people to report?

Comment: It is. I just like to hedge my bets a bit so we don't get reports if an update takes a bit longer or something.

Comment: The FAQ continues to say 'Monday' while we all know it updates automatically on Sunday..