# A query, days hitting rep cap vs days a member (rep)

Tags: support, reputation, data-explorer, daily-reputation-limit

I'm trying my best to create a custom query on Data Explorer but I think I've reached the limit of my own incompetence. I want it to identify;

1. The top 20 users on a given Stack Exchange community
2. How many days they've been a member
3. How many days they've hit the reputation cap (e.g. 200 points)

and then return (and rank) those results as a ordered percentage.

e.g.

- User 1 has been a member for 100 days and has hit the cap 100 times. His ratio is 100%
- User 2 has been a member for 100 days and has hit the cap 50 times. His ratio is 50%

Comment: Start with an existing query; this one looks relevant: http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/129634/days-hit-rep-cap

Answer (score 15):

I started off with the [query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/129634/days-hit-rep-cap) pointed out by [Martijn](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/140890/martijn-pieters) and ended up with [this beauty](https://data.stackexchange.com/scifi/query/204782/top-users-by-reputation-with-rep-cap-and-member-for-days)

*Be careful if you count rows when you are joining tables...*

Do note that these results might be slightly off because downvotes are anonymous so those votes on answers are not subtracted. SEDE is update weekly ([On Monday!?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/234398/158100)) so at best the data is off for a week.

```
;
with topusers as (select top 200 
                    id
                    , datediff(d , creationdate, getdate()) as Daysmember
             from users 
             order by reputation desc) ,
voting as (
         SELECT 
                SUM(case votes.votetypeid 
                        WHEN 1 THEN 15  -- accept
                        WHEN 2 THEN   -- upvote
                           CASE posts.posttypeid 
                              WHEN 1 THEN 5  -- upvote question
                              WHEN 2 THEN 10  -- upvote answer
                           END
                        WHEN 3 THEN -2  -- downvote
                        WHEN 9 THEN BountyAmount -- collected bounty
                 END) as Rep,
                 Votes.CreationDate AS CreationDate,
                 Posts.OwnerUserId 
          FROM   Posts
                 INNER JOIN Votes              
                   ON Votes.PostId = Posts.Id
                 INNER JOIN topusers t 
                    on t.id = Posts.OwnerUserId 
                      
          WHERE ( Posts.CommunityOwnedDate IS NULL ) 
          GROUP BY Votes.CreationDate,
                    Posts.OwnerUserId
),
bounty as (
         SELECT 
                SUM(-BountyAmount) as Rep,  -- Bounty given
                Votes.CreationDate AS CreationDate,
                Votes.UserID as OwnerUserId
          FROM  Votes                    
          INNER JOIN topusers t on t.id =  Votes.UserID
          WHERE votes.votetypeid = 8
          GROUP BY Votes.CreationDate,
                Votes.UserID
),
sugedit as (  -- suggested edits
          SELECT 
                 COUNT(*) * 2 as Rep 
               , cast(ApprovalDate as date) As CreationDate
               , OwnerUserId
          FROM  SuggestedEdits 
          INNER JOIN topusers t on t.id =  SuggestedEdits.OwnerUserId 
          WHERE ApprovalDate IS NOT NULL
          GROUP BY cast(ApprovalDate as date)
                 , OwnerUserId
)
select userid as [User Link]
, count(*) as [Days of Rep Cap]
, min(daysmember) [Days a member]
from (
select creationdate
       , userid
       , sum(votesrep + bountyrep + sugedtrep) as rep
    from (
    select v.creationdate as creationdate
         , v.owneruserid as userid
         , v.rep as votesrep
         , 0 as bountyrep
         , 0 as sugedtrep
    from voting v
    union
    select b.creationdate
          , b.owneruserid
          , 0
          , b.rep
          , 0
    from bounty b
    union 
    select s.creationdate
         , s.owneruserid
         , 0
         , 0
         , s.rep
    from sugedit s 
    ) as ingroup
    group by creationdate,
    userid
    having sum(votesrep + bountyrep + sugedtrep)>200
    ) cntdays
inner join topusers tu on tu.id = userid
group by userid
order by count(*) desc
```

The usual suspects on Stack Overflow are in the top result:

```
User Link     |Days of Rep Cap|Days a member
--------------------------------------------
Jon Skeet     |    2062       |   2101
Marc Gravell  |    1606       |   2098
Darin Dimitrov|    1558       |   2078
BalusC        |    1526       |   1776
Hans Passant  |    1444       |   2109
SLaks         |    1255       |   2062
VonC          |    1156       |   2114
CommonsWare   |    1139       |   1854
Greg Hewgill  |    1025       |   2148
Mark Byers    |     904       |   1971
```

### Explaination about this query

I based the functional requirements of this query on the FAQ item [How does “Reputation” work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7237/how-does-reputation-work). I'll match each bullet with the construction in the query so the query becomes verifiable (as requested in the comments). The text in `code` is the explanation.
*Votes and Posts are joined on Postid and Id*
*Userid is here 1 (Jeff Atwood on SO).*

#### You gain reputation when:

- one of your questions is voted up/useful: +5
  `Sum(5) from Votes where Votes.VoteTypeId == 2 and Post.PostTypeId = 1 and Post.OwnerUserId = 1`
- one of your answers is voted up/useful: +10
  `Sum(10) from Votes where Votes.VoteTypeId == 2 and Post.PostTypeId = 2 and Post.OwnerUserId = 1`
- one of your answers becomes accepted: +15
  `Sum(15) from Votes where Votes.VoteTypeId == 1 and Post.PostTypeId = 1 and Post.OwnerUserId = 1`
- you accept an answer written by someone else to one of your own questions: +2
  `un accounted for yet`
- a downvote on one of your questions or answers is removed: +2
  `this is not available in SEDE`
- you suggest an edit and it is accepted: +2 (up to a total of +1000 per user)
  `Sum(2) from SuggestedEdits where OwnerUserid = 1 and ApprovalDate is not null`
- you remove a downvote from an answer: +1
  `this is not available in SEDE (voting is anonymous)`
- one of your answers is awarded a bounty by the user offering the bounty: +full bounty amount
  `Sum(BountyAmount) from Votes where Votes.VoteTypeId == 9 and Post.PostTypeId = 2 and Post.OwnerUserId = 1`
- one of your answers is awarded a bounty automatically: +1/2 of the bounty amount (see bounty FAQ for details)
  `Sum(BountyAmount) from Votes where Votes.VoteTypeId == 9 and Post.PostTypeId = 2 and Post.OwnerUserId = 1`
- you associate accounts of two or more Stack Exchange network sites, and at least one of those accounts already has 200 or more reputation: +100 on each site (awarded a maximum of one time per site)
  `Not available in SEDE (there is no cross-site query possible)`

#### You lose reputation when:

- one of your questions or answers is voted down/not useful: −2
  `Sum(5) from Votes where Votes.VoteTypeId == 3 and Post.OwnerUserId = 1`
- a post where you had successfully suggested an edit has been deleted (reputation page shows the cause as "removed"): -2
  `this is not in SEDE`
- you vote an answer down/not useful: −1
  `this is not in SEDE`
- an upvote on one of your questions is removed: −5
  `this event is not in SEDE (but not needed if you're intersted in totals)`
- an upvote on one of your answers is removed: −10
  `this event is not in SEDE (but not needed if you're intersted in totals)`
- one of your accepted answers loses accepted status: −15
  `this event is not in SEDE (but not needed if you're intersted in totals)`
- you unaccept an answer written by someone else to one of your own questions: -2
  `this event is not in SEDE (but not needed if you're intersted in totals)`
- you place a bounty on a question: −full bounty amount
  `Sum(-BountyAmount) from Votes (unjoinded with Posts!) where Votes.UserId =1`
- one of your posts receives 6 spam or "it is not welcome in our community" flags (formerly known as offensive flags): −100
  `this is not in SEDE`

Comment: The results I get (when I run the same query on Scifi Stackexchange) aren't making any sense; http://oi61.tinypic.com/v5zfbd.jpg. The number of days seems accurate but the "times hit the rep cap" are completely wrong.

Comment: @Richard That was somewhat emabarrising but I believe this gives now better results...sorry...

Comment: It works much better now, but the cap results are still incorrect. The scores I get with this; http://data.stackexchange.com/scifi/query/167539/epic-legendary-progress-which-days-were-it don't seem to match up

Comment: That query is wrong for the bounties and for upvotes on questions and answers and doesn't take suggested edits into account

Comment: It can't be right. According to this, DVK (legendary) has only hit the rep cap 218 times :-) ; http://data.stackexchange.com/scifi/query/edit/204793#resultSets

Comment: hmmm, there are some subtle differences....

Comment: An upvote on a question is only 5 rep, on an answer it is 10. If I compensate the legendary for that the results only diffee for three days. Also the rep cap at 200 or 201? That would be an off-by-one bug.

Comment: So how do I correct the rep cap error? Other searches seem to be able to generate an accurate count but I can't see what they're doing right that this is doing wrong

Comment: Well, on [this](http://data.stackexchange.com/scifi/query/167539/epic-legendary-progress-which-days-were-it) the rep for votetypeid=8 is wrong, I don't know why you get +2 for votetypeid=16 and it doesn't count rep for suggestededits. That are the things I take into account.

Comment: So how do we fix it? I mean short of running both searches and then just dumping the output into Excel :-)

Comment: Maybe a wise thing to do is to ask a new question where you bring those different queries together and ask which is the best approximation. I'm happy to dig into that tomorrow...