# Why are query's reputation and real reputaion not same?

Tags: support, data-explorer

[I'm StackOverflow user, which has 2872 reputation.](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2729109/ikh)

While working with [stack exchange queries](https://data.stackexchange.com/), I found a strange point: reputaion query shows is *not* equal to the real reputation.

Here's my mcve: https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/edit/221534

```
SELECT Reputation FROM Users WHERE Id = 2729109
```

Result:

```
2600
```

Why does this dismatch happen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The data in SEDE is updated weekly. As of the past few months at least, it seems to be updated every Sunday around 3AM UTC.

So the reputation you earned from this week has not been added to SEDE as of yet.

Comment: It's actually Monday, according to http://data.stackexchange.com/help#faq

Comment: @MichaelMrozek that is wrong. See this http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/234390/sede-faq-small-discrepancy-update-day

Comment: I read that answer like 8 times and still don't understand if he's saying it's Sunday or Monday, but I guess it doesn't particularly matter

Comment: @MichaelMrozek *I* don't even know, which I guess is the issue.