# Is it possible to see pending flags on a post?

Tags: support, flags, low-quality-posts

I'm pretty active on a niche tag on Stack Overflow but we get a lot of completely useless questions that are unanswerable or obvious duplicates of questions either elsewhere or in the tag.

Normally, I flag these as either VLQ or duplicate, but it's difficult to get these questions closed as there are very few active users on the tag.

I was wondering if there's any way of seeing any pending flags on questions (and answers I guess) to see if others are also flagging the post as VLQ or a duplicate?

Comment: It’s arguably better not to flag questions as VLQ but instead give the intended close reason directly. This way, it would be sent to the close queue directly and would not take the long way via the VLQ queue (see also [this question of mine](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/239688/255554)).

Comment: That's fine for people with 3k+ rep but I'm not there yet (pickings are pretty slim in niche tags).

Comment: I am not talking about voting to close, I am talking about flagging to close, which only needs 15 reputation: question that is not your own → *flag* → *it should be closed for another reason...* → select close reason.

Comment: It's not clear how this would help you. If a question is flagged as duplicate, an automatic comment "possible duplicate of..." is added, and you can already see that. You don't see VLQ but (as Wrzlprmft noted) there isn't much need for this flag on _questions_. Also, it would be natural to _downvote_  those useless questions; everyone can see the score, and 1000+ users can also see the downvote count.

Answer (score 7):

Not live<sup>1</sup> but you could use [SEDE](https://data.stackexchange.com/) to find posts with pendingflags for a tag with [this query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/242640/pendingflags-on-a-tag?tag=haskell):

```
select pf.postid as [Post Link]
     , pf.creationdate
     , ft.Name
     , ft.description
from pendingflags  pf
inner join posts p on p.id =pf.postid
inner join posts q on q.id = p.id or q.id = p.parentid
inner join posttags pt on pt.postid = q.id
inner join tags t on t.id = pt.tagid
inner join flagtypes ft on pf.flagtypeid = ft.id
where t.tagname = ##tag:string##
order by pf.creationdate
```

To get help with flagging you could leave [cv-pls](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/89?m=2561501#2561501) requests in some chatrooms. Here on meta the [Tavern](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/rooms/89/tavern-on-the-meta) or on SO the [SO Close voters room](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41570/so-close-vote-reviewers) are watched for such request and if the members agree they will follow your vote.

<sub>1. The data is updated early every Monday morning around 3:00 UTC (from the [FAQ](https://data.stackexchange.com/help)) *(in reality the restore job runs on [sunday 3:00 UTC](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/234390/sede-faq-small-discrepancy-update-day))*</sub>

Comment: The data has actually been updating ***Sunday*** Morning around 3AM UTC, since like all of 2014. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/234390/sede-faq-small-discrepancy-update-day But, I guess they don't want to put the change in writing just yet.

Comment: @cVplZ Thanks for pointing that out, I added your info to my answer, including your link