# Possible SEDE migration failure

Tags: bug, status-completed, migration, data-explorer

Although it seems there's no SLA for the promptness of the weekly migration, it is unusually late this week for data migration to have not been completed.

I raise this only as feedback of the possible existence of a problem (not because some real or implied SLA has not been met).

---

Data migration now completed - approximately 8 hours later than usual.

Comment: Well, on the other hand, according to the [FAQ](http://data.stackexchange.com/help#faq) it isn't late, since that speaks about *"every Monday morning around 3:00 UTC"* ;-) (But I know what you mean and this is more a hint to the higher powers to possibly finally update that FAQ once this is fixed.)

Comment: @ChristianRau discrepancy has already been reported https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/234390/sede-faq-small-discrepancy-update-day , but I guess they're waiting for it to run 100 times consecutively without borking up before they feel comfortable changing it :o

Comment: @nic in case you're going to report it - no bug. For short while after suspension is over, the user still has 1 rep. (the recalc takes few minutes to trigger/run)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The initial update today ran out of space:

> Well, this is embarrassing. The VM we’re temporarily running Data Explorer on ran out of space during the weekly update. A fix is underway.

https://twitter.com/StackStatus/status/610034097314992129

A rerun of the update is currently occurring and should end within about 2 hours.

> A re-run of the weekly Stack Exchange Data Explorer data refresh is now underway. It will take approximately 3 hours to complete.

https://twitter.com/StackStatus/status/610035440490557440