# SEDE not fully-up-to-date after last "update"

Tags: bug, status-completed, data-explorer

According to this [previous bug report](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/264114/sede-migration-failed), SEDE had error so it did not update at [usual time](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/234390/sede-faq-small-discrepancy-update-day). The bug report was marked [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed). Even though SEDE says it "updated 14 hours ago", it isn't providing the new data from the previous week.

#### It appears that every site in SEDE is updated (even meta.SO), *except* for Stack Overflow.

[image]

Here's a [query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/205012/did-my-contribution-based-on-the-timestamp-made-it-into-sede) I use a lot to verify SEDE been updated with newest data.

[image]

Comment: nice freehand monsters!

Comment: I checked a few sites _other than SO_; they all have fresh data now. SO doesn't, probably because of [some issues](https://twitter.com/Nick_Craver/status/634813457611800576) with the SQL server dedicated to it. (The rest of the network uses another SQL server).

Comment: Reproduced for [movies.se], too (e.g. with [this query](http://data.stackexchange.com/movies/query/346866)). It seems to be frozen at last week's update (16.08.)...Hmm, wait, your test query gives 24.08. Seems there's just some weird caching involved on my side.

Comment: I have made update to your post. [status-completed] was changed to [status-planned] by jmac ♦

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There were still some gremlins in the update process. After fixing some certificate issues, restarting SQL Server, creating SPNs for the service account, and cleaning up the OUs and GPOs in New York it appears the import job has completed successfully.*

SEDE should now have data up to [2015-08-25](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/205012/did-my-contribution-based-on-the-timestamp-made-it-into-sede):

[image]

* Most of these are unrelated, but once you start looking for issues you usually find [a string of them](http://i.minus.com/ibaDjk7AeIcvxv.gif).

Comment: something went wrong again this week https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/264457/ooooooops-it-did-it-again