# Oops, it did it again - SEDE didn't update for Stack Overflow

Tags: support, data-explorer

Last week's SEDE update [left out](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/264190/sede-not-fully-up-to-date-after-last-update) poor Stack Overflow. And it did it again this week.

[This SO query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/205012/did-my-contribution-based-on-the-timestamp-made-it-into-sede) only returns results up to 8/25/2015, while it seems for every other site it correctly returns results [up to 8/30/2015](https://data.stackexchange.com/lifehacks/query/205012/did-my-contribution-based-on-the-timestamp-made-it-into-sede).

Comment: Why the [help page](http://data.stackexchange.com/help) says "The data is updated early every Monday morning around 3:00 UTC"

Comment: @HackerKarma: the help page is notoriously out of date; it has been updating on Sundays for ages now.

Comment: @MartijnPieters May be I should make a fea-req then

Comment: @HackerKarma: [SEDE FAQ - small discrepancy - update day](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/234390)

Comment: @MartijnPieters thanks for the link... avoided one dupe.

Comment: @HackerKarma: and read rene's answer carefully. :-)

Comment: @Geoff by removing the bug tag it means you won't be fixing it? (i.e. it might be long weeks befoe SEDE is updated again for SO), or did I miss something?

Comment: No, it's not a bug.  We will be switching back to NY here this evening and have our primary server available for SEDE which will fix this issue.

Comment: @Geoff why all the switching between locations? Is this explained somewhere? (just curious :))

Comment: https://www.stackstatus.net/ is where we post most of our updates.  We are also making sure that both data centers are ready to roll in the event of a natural disaster.  There's no better way than by actually running our sites in the backup location for awhile.

Comment: Also:  https://twitter.com/StackStatus is a good place to find updates.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Let me answer on behalf of Nick Craver:

> Though we'll be a little rocky making this time until we're back in New York - it's when it should happen!
>
> For the curious:
> We have a kerberos pass-through auth issue that's ~ 60% likely to fail in the refresh for complicated reasons. Ultimately we need to restart the Colorado SQL servers to use the correct SPNs for Kerberos...and we don't want to do that while they're live for hopefully obvious reasons :)

This was left as a comment on my pull request to fix the day mentioned in the FAQ: [Change the FAQ to mention Sunday as the update date](https://github.com/StackExchange/StackExchange.DataExplorer/pull/71#issuecomment-136005322)

Comment: +1 rene == SQL. You must have some kinda 'alert' system for SQL related questions.

Comment: @HackerKarma not in the [top 3 all-time yet...](http://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/data-explorer/topusers)

Comment: No worry... you will get there soon. Also, if I exclude SE team then you're a topper in the all-time list.

Comment: @HackerKarma Tim Stone isn't part of SE team and never was. :)