# A mysterious "StackOverflow_Temp" database appeared in the Data Explorer

Tags: discussion, data-explorer

Sometime within the past few weeks, [a mysterious database named `StackOverflow_Temp` appeared in the Data Explorer](https://data.stackexchange.com/meta.stackexchange/query/359956). The Data Explorer user cannot actually `USE` this database:

> The server principal "STACKEXCHANGE\svc_sede" is not able to access the database "StackOverflow_Temp" under the current security context.

Is this database supposed to be there? What's it for, if anything?

(Not that it probably matters a whole lot; I just noticed this since one of my queries that cursor-loops over all databases decided to throw an error at me.)

---

Update as of 13 Sept 2015 - the database has vanished. I'm guessing this was a transient issue, maybe related to the refresh/failover/whatever that rene mentioned in the comments (https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/264459/).

Comment: +1 for the good observation.

Comment: Might be related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/264459/158100